# "Contract constrains failed" error happened after replacing old kotlin-source.jar file

Tags: corda

We updated our Corda api code and generate a new package, to only deploy a CorDapp to all test nodes includes notaries and network map, we only replace original kotlin-source.jar under each node's plugin folder with a new version of kotlin-source.jar, but after restart the nodes, when we try to proceed one previous record, "Contract constrains failed" error happened and below is the error message found in the log. As all nodes are using the same version of kotlin-source.jar, I thought they are using the same CorDapp, anyone can provide a comment about what should be the contract constrains failed here? Thanks.

```
[WARN ] 2018-04-10T08:32:57,792Z [Node thread] flow.[d60cb4c4-f5b5-4b46-b8b2-9751165f5f34].run - Flow finished with exception
net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractConstraintRejection: Contract constraints failed for com.legalcontract.contract.LegalContractCode, transaction: 4A6A9F6EA45CB10C92EA406F9D3E378D7BA334DC0EB48009E54A2FDA9CF86E59
at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verifyConstraints(LedgerTransaction.kt:91) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:67) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.verify(TransactionBuilder.kt:113) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
at com.legalcontract.flow.LegalContractFlow$Initiator.call(LegalContractFlow.kt:261) ~[kotlin-source.jar:?]
at com.legalcontract.flow.LegalContractFlow$Initiator.call(LegalContractFlow.kt:47) ~[kotlin-source.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_162]
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Corda 3, unless you specify otherwise, a transaction specifies which contracts govern it using `HashAttachmentConstraint`s.

A `HashAttachmentConstraint` specifies what the hash of the JAR file that contains the contract must be. This means that if you change the contract - *or any file within that JAR* - the JAR hash will change and the contract will no longer be recognised.

You need to explicitly upgrade the contracts using Corda's explicity contract upgrade functionality. See the Contract Upgrades sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples) and the docs [here](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html).